# matlab functions works wrong

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I trying to make such function in matlab
[image]

It must be an array of `l_k` wheres `k` `from 1 to n` but however.

In code: `x` - some vector(array), `z` - scalar; in code `w` is upper part of frac and `g` is lower.

```
function out_l =  l_k(z, x)
%вычисления массива l_k для числа z
%x - узлы интерполяции
%z - значение для которог овычисляем значение полинома
n = size(x);
w = 1;
g = 1;
out_l = zeros(n);

for k = 1:n

    for j = 1:n
    %вычислим w
        for i=1:n
            if((i ~= k) && (i ~= j))
                w = w * (z - x(i));
            end
        end
    %вычислим g
        for i=1:n
            if(i ~= k)
                g = g * (x(k) - x(i));
            end
        end

    end
    out_l(k) =  (w/g);  
end
end
```

The problem is - when it comes to this for cycles it's just exits after first time checking if statement! What's worng?

```
 %вычислим w
            for i=1:n
                if((i ~= k) && (i ~= j))
                    w = w * (z - x(i));
                end
            end
        %вычислим g
            for i=1:n
                if(i ~= k)
                    g = g * (x(k) - x(i));
                end
            end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `n = size(x);` doesn't make sense if you want the number of elements in `n` (`size` returns a row vector of dimensions, not a scalar). Try `n=numel(x);` instead.

**Later edit:** I also see that you allocate your output data like this: `out_l = zeros(n);`, but you should be aware that it creates a nxn matrix, not an array as you may expect. Try `out_l = zeros(1,n);` for a change.

And another advice: when in doubt, use the F1 key as often as possible. :-) The Matlab integrated help is very good at explaining Matlab stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has embedded functions to perform interpolation such as [interp1](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html); (I can recognize Lagrange interpolation functions in your formula).

If you want to have your own code to evaluate Lagrange interpolation functions, you should consider to use vectors and avoid loops so to make your code faster.

Consider the following:

```
x_n = 0:.3:1; % # interpolation nodes

k = 3;        % # we want for instance the function which is equal to 1 at 3rd node  

z = .5;       % # we want to evaluate the interpolant at z=.5


x_n_l = x_n;
x_n_l(k) = [];   % # we need all the nodes but the k-th

l_k = prod( z - x_n_l )/prod( x_n(k) - x_n_l ) % # this is your value
```

Of course you can wrap the code in a nice function.

Comment: oh it looks complicated -_-

Comment: i never used matlab before until last week